# Can someone clarify what is happening in this part of the code?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, web

So I have part of code like this

```
ruter.get('/', async function (_, res) {
const [categories, items] = (await Promise.all([
    db.query('SELECT * FROM categories'),
    db.query('SELECT * FROM inventory'),
])).map(result => result.rows);

for (const category of categories) {
    category.items = items.filter(item => (item.categoryid === category.id));
}
```

I have database where I have table-categories and table-items
categories table and items look like this:

[image]

[image]

What I don't understand is what happens with categories and inventory in this part of code ->

```
   db.query('SELECT * FROM categories'),
    db.query('SELECT * FROM inventory'),
])).map(result => result.rows);
```

Do they get joined? Also in this part

```
category.items = items.filter(item => (item.categoryid === category.id));
```

what item means here, there is no column named item in items table?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
const [categories, items] = (await Promise.all([
    db.query('SELECT * FROM categories'),
    db.query('SELECT * FROM inventory'),
])).map(result => result.rows);
```

- makes two queries - one from categories, one from inventory
- in parallel, with `Promise.all`
- then takes the `rows` property from each query result and puts those into the `categories` and `items` variables.

They don't get joined - they're two entirely independent queries and get put into separate `categories` and `items` variables.

> what item means here

With

```
items.filter(item =>
```

`items` is the result of the query `SELECT * FROM inventory` - `item` is a single row from that query.

Comment: thank you, would it matter if I used another name instead of item, for intanse 'it', i think not? but not sure

Comment: No, it's just a parameter name, which could be anything you wanted. `.filter(item =>` or `.filter(row =>` etc

Comment: But if they are two independant queries (categories and items) than what would category.items mean? I know category is a row from table categories, but table categories doesn't have column named items? that confuses me

Comment: The code assigns the relevant items to a property of the category record for easier access later on. You are right that it has no items column in the database - here the code _creates_ such a property (locally), based on the filtered results of the items query.

Comment: That line there `category.items = items.filter(item =>` is essentially adding one more column (or property) to each `category` row (or object). It's only changing the JS variables, not the underlying database. The actual table does not have such a column.

Comment: So, in a way, you _could_ say they get joined, sort of - but not on an SQL level. At the end you have a structure like `[{id:..., someCategoryColumn:..., items: [{id:..., someItemColumn:...}, ...]}, ...]` in `categories`.

Comment: Ok I think it is perfectly clear now but let me just summarize it to see if I understand it completely, so we have tables categories and items, by doing  db.query('SELECT * FROM categories'),
    db.query('SELECT * FROM inventory'), I made two variables where I stored rows from those two tables, now by doing category.items in every category of categories i make new row items with items stored depending if they satisfy (item.categoryid === category.id)

Thank you once again

Comment: Since you're doing the new manipulations in JavaScript, not in the SQL, it'd be more appropriate to say you're adding a new property to each category object, rather than a new column to the categories table.